# Can we check item sub-type in netsuite advanced pdf?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript, invoice

I am showing invoice line items on invoice advanced pdf template. Now I have add condition for quantity field that, I want to show quantity if item is non- inventory item and sub type is sale. Is it possible to check item sub-type without using script. In advanced pdf template?

Below is my item table:
<#if record.item?has_content>

```
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -5px;"> 
<!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr style="border-bottom:1px;">

    <th colspan="12">${item.description@label}</th>
      <th align="center" colspan="4">Number Of Users</th>
    <th colspan="2">${item.quantity@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">Unit Price</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>

    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br 
/>${item.description}</td>
  <td colspan="4">${item.quantity}</td>
  <td align="center" colspan="2" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list><!-- end items --></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check item subtype by using item.itemsubtype